# How to take a screenshot of the screen of a Surface Pro Windows 10 without login and using a camera?

Tags: windows-10, screenshot, microsoft-surface-pro-4

How to take a screenshot of the screen of a Surface Pro 4 (Windows 10) without login and without using a camera device? (meaning that at the login screen of the Surface Pro 4, one can take a screenshot without using a camera device, whereby a camera device include phone's camera)

This is because the Surface Pro 4 has a wireless icon on the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

- You can easily press the **‘Power’ + ‘Volume Down’** button to take screenshot on both Surface Pro 4 and Surface Book (tablet mode without keyboard).

Source: [How to take a screenshot on the Microsoft Surface Pro 4 & Surface Book by hardware key combo](http://www.windowsalle.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-the-microsoft-surface-pro-4-surface-book-by-hardware-key-combo/).

I don't own a Surface 4 so can't test it myself.

Comment: It does not work when you are at the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

You mean without logging in to the Windows 10 system?

I don't know how you would take a screenshot "of the Surface Pro 4", but you could always run Windows 10 in a VM. Then from the host machine, use PrtScr to take a screenshot that shows the VM's window.

Is there something different about how Windows 10's login screen looks on the Surface Pro that you want to capture?

Comment: yes, I need to include the wireless icon since the Surface Pro 4 come with the built in wireless adapter.